# Having trouble exact first-order differential equation.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I've been trying to solve the following differential equation:

$$3x+y(x)-2+\frac{dy(x)}{dx}(x-1)=0$$
And I found out it's an exact differential equation, since it can be rearranged as $(3x+y(x)-2)dx+(x-1)dy=0$

Assuming that a function $U(x,y)=\frac{\partial U}{\partial x}dx + \frac{\partial U}{\partial y}dy = k$, (where $k\equiv$ constant) exists, I calculated it as:

$$U(x,y)=\int (3x+y-2)dx + \int (x-1)dy=k$$

And I got $$y(x)=\frac{-3x^2}{2(2x-1)}+\frac{2x}{2x-1}+\frac{k}{2x-1}$$

But Mathematica says the solution is
$$y(x)=\frac{-3x^2}{2(x-1)}+\frac{2x}{x-1}+\frac{k}{1-x}$$

So either I assumed something which isn't correct or I made a mistake along the process. Where did I go wrong?

Thanks everyone in advance!

Comment: $3x+y(x)−2$ is different form $3x+y(x)−x$

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo

Comment: Well, your solution is correct! You can also double check your solution on [WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate%20(3x%2By%E2%88%922)dx%20%2B%20integrate%20(x%E2%88%921)dy%20%3D%20k)

Comment: How is it correct? I see what you linked, but WolframAlpha also gives a different solution from the one I got. Is it because you can play with the coefficients since there is an arbitrary constant?

Comment: @Manuel Check your solution again.

Comment: WolframAlpha gave the same solution you reported originally!! I don't see any mistake you did to solve U(x,y).

Comment: Oh, then I must have been distracted before! Thanks a lot, Shadi :)

Answer (score 0):

It can be seen as a linear differential equation:

$y' +\dfrac{y}{x-1} = \dfrac{2-3x}{x-1}$

Using integration factor $x-1$

$y(1-x)=\int(2-3x)dx$

$y (1-x) = 2x - \frac{3x^2}{2} + k$

Hope it helps